# How do I mount a IDE disk connected with USB?

Tags: hard-drive, usb, mount

So I bought a USB device that I connect different HDD to. IDE and SATA. It has a built in molex power adepter. The device works when I'm connecting SATA devices. Photorec works like a charm on SATA devices!

But I'm having some problems with the IDE disks. They are not showing up in finder. I can see that the USB device is recognized by the OS (10.12.6) in system report:

```
  Produkt-ID:   0x0611
  Tillverkar-ID:    0x1f75  (Innostor Co., Ltd.)
  Version:  0.06
  Serienummer:  20170228
  Hastighet:    Upp till 5 Gbit/sek
  Plats-ID: 0x14600000 / 12
  Tillgänglig ström (mA):   900
  Nödvändig ström (mA): 800
  Extra arbetsström (mA):   300
```

And the device shows up as `/dev/ttys000`. I have no clue what filesystem it is, maybe NTFS or fat32. If I run `diskutil list`, only my primary device for my workstation shows. My machine is a MacBook Pro mid 2014, i7.

This is the result when executing `$ system_profiler SPStorageDataType`

Storage:

```
Macintosh HD:

  Available: 140,13 GB (140 134 998 016 bytes)
  Capacity: 499,07 GB (499 071 844 352 bytes)
  Mount Point: /
  File System: Journaled HFS+
  Writable: Yes
  Ignore Ownership: No
  BSD Name: disk1
  Volume UUID: xxxx
  Logical Volume:
      Revertible: Yes (unlock and decryption required)
      Encrypted: Yes
      Encryption Type: AES-XTS
      Locked: No
      LV UUID: xxxx
  Logical Volume Group:
      Name: APPLE SSD SM0512F Media
      Size: 499,42 GB (499 418 034 176 bytes)
      Free Space: Zero KB
      LVG UUID: xxxx
  Physical Volumes:
    disk0s2:
      Device Name: APPLE SSD SM0512F
      Media Name: APPLE SSD SM0512F Media
      Size: 499,42 GB (499 418 034 176 bytes)
      Medium Type: SSD
      Protocol: PCI
      Internal: Yes
      Partition Map Type: GPT (GUID Partition Table)
      Status: Online
      S.M.A.R.T. Status: Verified
      PV UUID: xxxx
```

Comment: What Mac model?  What drive identifier?  Can you *please* edit the original question with the specifics?  Do you know if this IDE to USB device works?  Do you know if the drive is good?  How are you powering it?

Comment: Please issue the command `system_profiler SPStorageDataType` and post the output to your queston

Comment: see updated question

Comment: I'm assuming the USB and IDE drive is plugged in?